# Scrapy: How to tell if robots.txt exists

Tags: python, scrapy, robots.txt

I know I can check by myself if a robots.txt file exists using python and firing an http(s) request. Since Scrapy is checking and downloading it in order to have a spider respect the rules in it, is there a property or method or anything in the Spider class that allows me to know if robots.txt exists for the given website to be crawled?

Tried with crawler stats:

See [here](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/e27eff47ac9ae9a9b9c43426ebddd424615df50a/scrapy/downloadermiddlewares/robotstxt.py#L97)

```
self.crawler.stats.inc_value(f'robotstxt/response_status_count/{response.status}')
```

I did a couple of tests with websites having and not having robots.txt and I could see the proper info on robots.txt existence. For example, logging `self.crawler.stats.__dict__` in my Spider class in my spider_close signal handler I see:

`'robotstxt/response_status_count/200': 1` website with robots.txt
`'robotstxt/response_status_count/404': 1` website without robots.txt

Well this does not work if during the crawling the spider meets several domains, and the result in stats would be something like:

```
"robotstxt/response_status_count/200": 1,
"robotstxt/response_status_count/301": 6,
"robotstxt/response_status_count/404": 9,
"robotstxt/response_status_count/403": 1
```

but I can't map HTTP status code responses to domains...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so, you would probably have to make a custom middleware based on `RobotsTxtMiddleware`. It has the methods `_parse_robots` and `_robots_error`, you could probably use them to determine if robots.txt existed.

https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/e27eff47ac9ae9a9b9c43426ebddd424615df50a/scrapy/downloadermiddlewares/robotstxt.py

Comment: Thanks Felix. I've edited my question with some more details. You're right, there's no other way (inside Scrapy) to intercept the response than with a custom middleware that catches robots.txt requested and eventually writes stats somewhere.
I've created that simple middleware and it works but I don't like the idea to observe every single Scrapy request for my goal. Probably in my tool (of which Scrapy is just a component)I will just make a HTTP(s) request and will not use middleware. Maybe a PR to original RobotsTxtMiddleware to get this info could be useful. I will bug them on github :)